# Firebase Firestore Nested Query retrieving both results

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to get results from firestore

```
db.collection("dialogs")
            .whereArrayContains("members", me.getId())
            .get()
            .continueWith(continue -> {
                List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : continue.getResult())
                    for (Object userId : (ArrayList) snapshot.get("members"))
                        tasks.add(db.collection("users").document(userId.toString()).get());
                return tasks;
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(task -> {
                for (Object something : task)
                    Log.d("Query", "Data: " + something);
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d("Query", "Exception: " + e));
```

this code will give me the `users` documents as seen above, what i want as well is the document id of `snapshot`

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, `continue` isn't a document, it's a Task that contains a DocumentSnapshot result.  Your [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) is in `snapshot`, and you can get the id of a DocumentSnapshot using its [getId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getId()) method.

```
val id = snapshot.getId()
```

Comment: and how can i pass the snapshot's id to the listener?

Comment: will you please help me figure this out?